# Getting rid of escape character in Python so that data can be converted to JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-requests, backslash, html-escape-characters

I am getting some data out of the cmd terminal through git log and transporting that data to a JSON file. I parsed out the required data out of that JSON file and intended to put that data into a new JSON type data so that this data can be used in the requests.put() method to update a webpage.
So that data is a string and after I parse it out from the initial JSON file that gets created from the git log looks like:

```
This is the \\\'data\\\'
```

So from the JSON file I put that data string into a variable called "data" and so that string above is in the variable data.
When I physically open that JSON file the data looks normal as in the escape backslash is now visible like:

```
This is the 'data'
```

So in my code I tried printing the data and the printable representation of the data like

```
print(data)
print(repr(data))
```

And I can see in my terminal that the printed data looks like:

```
This is the \\\'data\\\'
This is the \\\\\\\'data\\\\\\\'
```

I am later trying to insert that data into a new JSON structure and doing json.loads(json_struc) which displays an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1  column 21605 (char 21604)
```

I tried replacing the escape characters using string.replace() method but it does not work as the method cannot detect the "\'". When I tried to do that experiment in a new python file by putting that data into a variable and using string.replace() it works but not when the value is parsed out of that initial JSON. For example doing this works fine:

```
strin = "This is the \\\'data\\\'"

if "\\\'" in strin:
    print("Replacing character")
    print(strin.replace("\\\'", "&#039;"))
```

I am trying to replace that single quote with ' since this data is part of an html data to be posted on a webpage and so certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.

So this is what I tried in my script with no success:

```
#data contains "This is the \\\'data\\\'"
if "\\\'" in data:
  data_string = data.replace("\\\'", "&#039;")
```

Thing is that this if-statement actually never gets executed in my script since compiler thinks this statement is False. But it should get executed since we have "\'" in data.
What should my change be such that json.loads() work? Need to somehow neglect the escape backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already tried, this. you can use json.dumps(create a string) and then perform the loads.

```
strin = "This is the \\\'data\\\'"
j_string=json.dumps(strin)
print(j_string) # "This is the \\'data\\'"
print(json.loads(j_string)) # "This is the \\'data\\'"
```

or you can try like following and it will work too.

```
strin = r"This is the \\\'data\\\'"
```